# Mini Arducam module camera shield - 2MP ov2640 interface with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, shields, camera

[MINI ARDUCAM MODULE CAMERA SHIELD - 2MP OV2640](https://robu.in/product/arducam-mini-module-camera-shield-with-ov2640-2-mp-lens-for-arduino/)

[Arducam Multi-camera adapter board for Arduino SPI Mini Camera](https://robu.in/product/arducam-multi-camera-adapter-board-for-arduino-spi-mini-camera/)

I have the above two components with me along with ARDUINO UNO R3.
I want to stream video using these. ARDUCAM provides library for this.

[**ARDUCAM LIBRARY**](https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino)

[**ARDUCAM DATASHEET**](https://www.arducam.com/downloads/shields/ArduCAM_Camera_Shield_Software_Application_Note.pdf)

When I have chosen example program **ArduCAM_Shield_V2_Video_Streaming** and tried uploading it to Arduino it showed no ***ArduCAM.h: No such file or directory***.

[image]

I have downloaded the library and kept it in the libraries folder of ARDUINO.

Can someone help me out with this??

Comment: what's the picture with the horizontal orange bar? ... difficult to see

Comment: how are you going to stream video from the arduino?

Comment: did you install the library?

Comment: The error message in the image (*”ArduCAM.h: no such file or directory”*) can only mean that the library hasn’t been installed correctly.

Comment: As Nick Gammon wrote: There is no way, that you are sending video with an Uno. Its just not up to the task

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07UwmbeFCZQ

Comment: Please refer this YouTube Video

Answer (score 1):

The Uno which you mention has 2 KB of RAM. 2 MP of data would be 2,000,000 x 3 bytes (red, green, and blue), in other words 6 MB.

The screenshot you showed seems to show that the library is designed to take a still photo and buffer it. As you might imagine, buffering 6 MB would take a while, especially as you can only fit 2 KB at a time.

You simply won't be streaming video using the Uno, so the error message is more-or-less irrelevant.

It might be relevant if you actually wanted to take single photos and send them.

In that case, you probably haven't installed the library properly.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07UwmbeFCZQ

Comment: Please refer the YouTube Video above...

Comment: Yeah, OK. I can't see the resolution but that looks like a whole series of stills at about 1 frame per second. I suppose you can call that "streaming video" if you want to have a security camera taking photos of a room in your house. I assumed by "video" you meant what most people would call video, namely around 24 FPS or more.